How to include "Proxies" information in Autodesk APS_SDK
Autodesk APS SDK includes the following parts related to 3-legged authentication.
The getThreeLeggedToken method in the npm package "@aps_sdk/authentication" has a special part that takes "optionalArgs."
getThreeLeggedToken(clientId, code, redirect_uri, optionalArgs) {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
            if (optionalArgs === null || optionalArgs === void 0 ? void 0 : optionalArgs.clientSecret) {
                const clientIDSecret = Buffer.from(`${clientId}:${optionalArgs === null || optionalArgs === void 0 ? void 0 : optionalArgs.clientSecret}`).toString(`base64`);
                const response = yield this.tokenApi.fetchToken(`Basic ${clientIDSecret}`, GrantType.AuthorizationCode, code, redirect_uri, optionalArgs === null || optionalArgs === void 0 ? void 0 : optionalArgs.code_verifier, undefined, undefined, undefined, optionalArgs === null || optionalArgs === void 0 ? void 0 : optionalArgs.options);
                return response.content;
            }
            else {
                const response = yield this.tokenApi.fetchToken(undefined, GrantType.AuthorizationCode, code, redirect_uri, optionalArgs === null || optionalArgs === void 0 ? void 0 : optionalArgs.code_verifier, undefined, undefined, clientId, optionalArgs === null || optionalArgs === void 0 ? void 0 : optionalArgs.options);
                return response.content;
            }
        });
    }

I want to know how to include proxy information in these optionalArgs or modify the module-related code below to make requests with proxy information included.
